# Unable to instantiate receiver GCMBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-manifest

I am following a guide at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ for GCM.

Currently I am stuck at the part at receiving notifications.
Sometimes when i run my codes, it would crash with this error:

> > 7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.someactivity-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.someactivity-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2544)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.someactivity-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.someactivity-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
> >     7.517: E/AndroidRuntime(8601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2539)

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.someactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.someactivity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.someactivity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.someactivity.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.example.someactivity.fragmentContainer" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.someactivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my receiver which i used:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("Some Message");
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */

        // Showing received message       
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

Why am I getting receiver not instantiated, I have changed the package names already.

Comment: did you instantiate the mHandleMessageReceiver to recieve messages?

Comment: registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.someactivity.DISPLAY_MESSAGE")); Yup, I think the error lies in the manifest though

Comment: did you make the reference to the google play services library correctly?

Comment: I can register the device, so I guess it is working, I'm trying to add gcm.jar now

Comment: yes you have to add gcm.jar in your libs folder

Comment: adding gcm.jar worked. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add gcm.jar to your libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure receiver package name is correct in manifest